# Firebase cloud function http request crashing

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send expo push notification via firebase cloud functions, in order to send notifications from the web app to devices that have downloaded the mobile app.

When I send the request from Postman, it works just fine... i get the ok response and the notification shows up on my phone. But when I try to make the request from the web app, i get this in the functions log:

> Function execution took 22 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

Any ideas why is this happening? Couldn't find anything to explain this so far.

Here's my function:

```
exports.reportNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const tokens = request.body.expoPushToken;
    let messages = [];
    tokens.forEach((token) =>
      messages.push({
        to: token,
        title: "title",
        body: "message",
        sound: "default",
        _displayInForeground: "true",
      })
    );

    fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(messages),
    })
      .then((res) => response.status(200).json({ res: res }))
      .catch((err) => response.status(400).json({ error: err }));
});
```

My post request on Postman:

```
{
    "expoPushToken": ["ExponentPushToken[xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx]"]
}
```

And I call the function with axios in the web app:

```
axios({
    url: "reportNotification",
    baseURL: functionsBaseURL,
    method: "post",
    data: {
        expoPushToken: tokens,
    },
})
```

I checked and the tokens on this request are in the same format that the one on Postman.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're writing the error in the response to the called here: `.catch((err) => response.status(400).json({ error: err }));`. So if you log this response, what does it show?

Comment: It says it's a network error, nothing more.
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)

Answer (score 1):

It was a cors problem, solved with this modification:

```
exports.reportNotification = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    const tokens = request.body.expoPushToken;
    let messages = [];
    tokens.forEach((token) =>
      messages.push({
        to: token,
        title: "title",
        body: "message",
        sound: "default",
        _displayInForeground: "true",
      })
    );

    axios.post("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", JSON.stringify(messages), {
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => response.status(200).json({ res: res }))
      .catch((err) => response.status(200).json({ error: err }));
  });
});
```