# Firebase Functions send message to topic

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What I am trying to create is a function that simply sends notification to topic

So everything I do is just sending a channel name and  what I have is this

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
 
  const dest = req.query.dest;
  
  console.log(dest);
  console.log('Message received');
    

    const payLoad = {
        notification:{
            title: "Message title",
            body: "You have a new message"
        }
    };

    console.log("*** about to send message ");
     admin.messaging().sendToTopic(dest, payLoad).then((response) => {
      console.log("Successfully sent message ", response);
      return res.send(JSON.stringify({"success":"true"}));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
      return res.send(JSON.stringify({"success":"false"}));
  })
    
});
```

From the functions logs I have:

> 11:12:47.622 PM
> sendNotification
> Function execution started
>
> 11:12:47.704 PM
> sendNotification 9Td4I6aWOoVvNXWNE0pZYjwbXNv1
> 11:12:47.705 PM
> sendNotification Message received
> 11:12:47.720 PM
> sendNotification
> Function execution took 98 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

It seems that it's crashing when the payLoad is created, but I can't figure out why

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the entire content of your `index.js` file, including the `require` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer, as it is too long for a the *comment* section.

Could you please try adding this line of code:

```
{
  cors(request, response, () => {
```

as suggested from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524771/firebase-cloud-function-http-request-crashing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755131/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase) posts?

The poster from the first link seems to have received the exact same error with you and resolved it by enabling cors. You may find the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with).